# Setting up Facebook Comments and Like Button on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like, facebook-comments

I would like to install [Facebook Comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments) and [Like button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button) for Wordpress blog. So I set up this block of code right after `<body>`. The first part is Facebook SDK set for web, and I think that there is no error here. And the second part is a block of code for web application. (I have replaced appId with XXXXX.)

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'XXXXXX',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.4'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4&appId=XXXXXX";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Then I place Facebook Like Button right after single post.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>
```

And Facebook Comments after it.

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-numposts="3" data-width="100%" data-href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ?>" data-mobile="false"></div>
```

But in my [Wordpress temp demo](http://chenghuayang.com/blog/love-lorem-ipsum/#comments), Facebook Comments shows up and Like Button does not. Is there any wrong here?

Comment: It appears that `.facebook-sharer` needs an explicit width, e.g `60px`. Although I notice you're using flexbox for the parent container, your issue probably stems from the rules set on the children of the container.

Comment: @DavidAlsbright Thanks man. So the problem might be the outer container `.sharer-container`, which is flexbox, to wrap the inner container `.facebook-sharer` and make it 0px wide. (The structure is in the [link above](http://chenghuayang.com/blog/love-lorem-ipsum/#comments) or [the screenshot](http://imgur.com/RQW5ka3).) But I have no idea why  the inner container `.facebook-sharer` collapsed? Why it cannot act like the other sharers?

Comment: Also, it seems that the flexbox attribute did not take effect on `.sharer-container` as I turn it off in dev tools.

Comment: Is there a reason you're including the SDK twice?

Comment: Removing `width: 100% !important;` from line 406 (`.fb_iframe_widget`) seems to resolve it, it appears fine when that's removed...

Comment: @mevius I have noticed that, but there is some difference like `js.src...`. I do not quite sure if it is for loading different code or not. So is there any change we can do with it? (I am not quite familiar with JS.) @DavidAlsbright Too bad that `width: 100%` is the default setting from Facebook, I cannot change it via CSS.

Comment: This might help: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/problem-with-facebook-button-2

Comment: @DavidAlsbright Oops!!! Exactly my mistake. That was from my last test for Facebook Comments. :P

Comment: nice :) you should add as an answer in case it will help others in the future.

Comment: Sure, I will do it later! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally, I'd like to make the Facebook Comments flexible so give it a value 100% width. But in that case, I also unintentionally specified some div inside Facebook Like Button. So the 100% width of the child just make the parent collapsed, and the whole Like Button collapsed.

You can check the whole current structure of Facebook Like Button in [this temp demo](http://chenghuayang.com/blog/love-lorem-ipsum/#comments) or [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trkqD.jpg).